# Undefined offset when using array_chunk

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
$people = array(
            array(  'name'=>'Sarah',
                    'gender'=>'F'),
            array(  'name'=>'Darren',
                    'gender'=>'M'),
            array(  'name'=>'John',
                    'gender'=>'M'),
            array(  'name'=>'Phil',
                    'gender'=>'M'),
            array(  'name'=>'Alice',
                    'gender'=>'F'),
            array(  'name'=>'Sam',
                    'gender'=>'M'),
            );
```

I would like to get it to display in a 2 column structure as follows:

```
Sarah | Darren
John | Phil
Alice | Sam
```

I am using array_chunk and looping through as follows:

```
foreach(array_chunk($people, 2, true) as $array)
{
    ?>
    <div class="left"><?php echo $array[0]['name']; ?></div>
    <div class="right"><?php echo $array[1]['name']; ?></div>
    <?php
}
```

The above does not work because it says: `Undefined offset: 0`

The value of `print_r($array)` is:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Sarah [gender] => F ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Darren [gender] => M ) )
```

Comment: That array is already chunked. Look at array_column if you have php 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed `true` as the 3rd arg to [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php), that preserves keys.

`0` doesnt exist on the 2nd loop because the next available index would be `2`.

Remove the 3rd argument from array_chunk and you should have what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the output like this:

```
$count = 0;
foreach($people as $person) {
if($count % 2 == 0) {
    echo $person['name'] . ' | ';
} else {
    echo $person['name'] . '<br /><br />';
}
$count++;
}
```